# Evaluate formulas in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Is it possible to evaluate formulas in a dataframe which refer to columns? e.g. if I have data like this (Scala example):

```
val df = Seq(
    ( 1, "(a+b)/d", 1, 20, 2, 3, 1 ),
    ( 2, "(c+b)*(a+e)", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ),
    ( 3, "a*(d+e+c)", 7, 10, 6, 2, 1 )
  )
    .toDF( "Id", "formula", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" )

df.show()
```

Expected results:

[image]

I have been unable to get `selectExpr`, `expr`, `eval()` or combinations of them to work.

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop, I did review that answer but found those methods weren't particularly extensible, eg for many columns, so I was looking for something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: For many columns, you can replace variables per their corresponding values before calling eval directly in spark using replace function :  `expr(df.columns.drop(2).foldLeft("formula")((acc, c) => s"replace($acc, '$c', $c)"))`

Comment: @blackbishop, can you show that method in a dataframe evaluating to the expected results please?  I'm interested to try the different approaches at scale (50 columns, 1 million rows).

Comment: it's not about the evaluation of the expression but the replacement of the variable per their values from the other columns. To evaluate the expression you'll always need UDF. anyway, I added it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the scala toolbox eval in a UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

val cols = df.columns.tail
val eval_udf = udf(
    (r: Seq[String]) => 
    tb.eval(tb.parse(
        ("val %s = %s;" * cols.tail.size).format(
            cols.tail.zip(r.tail).flatMap(x => List(x._1, x._2)): _*
        ) + r(0)
    )).toString
)

val df2 = df.select(col("id"), eval_udf(array(df.columns.tail.map(col):_*)).as("result"))

df2.show
+---+------+
| id|result|
+---+------+
|  1|     7|
|  2|    12|
|  3|    63|
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different version of mck's answer, by replacing the variables in the `formula` column by their corresponding values from the other columns then calling eval udf :

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val eval = udf((f: String) => {
  val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
  toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(f)).toString
})


val formulaExpr = expr(df.columns.drop(2).foldLeft("formula")((acc, c) => s"replace($acc, '$c', $c)"))    
df.select($"Id", eval(formulaExpr).as("result")).show()

//+---+------+
//| Id|result|
//+---+------+
//|  1|     7|
//|  2|    12|
//|  3|    63|
//+---+------+
```